# Why doesn't python for loop use all values of my list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I think there's something really simple I'm missing in python 3 lists. Why doesn't my code process all of my list values (it doesn't process duplicates) and how to make it do that?

```
list = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5}
z = 0

for x in list:
    if x % 2 != 0:
        z += 1

print(z)
```

Thank You!

Comment: **Misnomer**: You have a set not a list. Sets do not allow duplicates.

Comment: list is in square brackets ie ls = [1,2,3,...]

Comment: `print(list)` will show you the problem...

Comment: You want: `list = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: Use `[]` or `()` instead of `{}` for list or tuple definition, correspondingly

Comment: DO NOT USE LIST AS A VARIABLE NAME. Really, don't, list is a builtin type, don't overload it.

Answer (score 2):

When you put values inside `{}` you create a *set*, not a *list*. The duplicated values are removed. So, your `list` variable has only the values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, in random order. To use an actual list, write `x = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]`.

Also, don't name your variable `list`, it shadows a built-in name.

Comment: *To use an actual list, write `x = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5}`*. Hmmm, incorrect.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: Yep, typo!!